How to format a citation of ChatGPT correctly for the mla bibliography?
I'm trying to cite something a certain way which was asked of me by my teacher. I want the result as explained in the tex code
\documentclass{article}
 
\usepackage[
    style=mla-new,
    backend=biber
]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{essay1.bib}
@online{chatgpt_communication,
    author = {ChatGPT},
    title = {Professional Communication},
    date = {2024-07-12},
    note = {Accessed: 12 July 2024}
}
\end{filecontents}
 
\addbibresource{essay1.bib}
 
\begin{document}

\autocite{chatgpt_communication}

What I'm trying to achieve: \vspace{\baselineskip}

\textit{ChatGPT}, ``Professional Communication,'' 12 July 2024.

\clearpage 
\printbibliography
 
\end{document}

ChatGPT, "Professional Communication", 12 July 2024.
However, I am having trouble as I looked into the biblatex doc and found that webpages are to use @online, but this doesn't seem to output the italic word in the works cited (they should only be italic in the works cited). Is there a fix to this? It would greately help out if I could get advice on how to get my result.

I do find it quite senseless to make a citation out of this. This is not a reference that anyone can or even would want to check.

I agree with Ulrike. This particular citation is next to useless and you might just as well write what you did directly into the text. But even ignoring this, the suggested citation does not appear to follow the general citation style of MLA style at all. MLA style usually only mentions author names and possibly the title (if there are more works by the same list of authors). In particular I'm confused about the italics you want. Do you want italics of "ChatGPT" only in the citations, only in the works cited or in both settings?
